# How to send HTML form data to Python server using AJAX or similar?

Tags: python, ajax, http, server, webserver

I am completely new to this so apologies if the question is a bit vague. I need to know where to start.

I am trying to make a simple setup with the following flow:

1. User uploads a CSV file to HTML form, file is sent (see below) to
   the server.
2. Server is running a python script that takes the CSV and
   turns it into an array.
3. The python script runs functions on the
   array and makes a new array of information.
4. This new array is sent
   back to the HTML webpage as an array that will be shown to the user
   through Javascript DOM.

I know how to do everything on the front-end and the processing in python. My question is, how would the file be sent to the server (would the form be submitted with GET or POST, etc.) and how can I make this like the diagram attached? Any guidance is appreciated.

## Edit 5/10/20

My front-end code would look like this:

```js
function sendfile(){
  var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile").value;
  $.post('localhost:22222', //this is where I am hosting the server
         {SendData: file},
          function(returnedArray) {
            var newData = //the response from python server, in array format;
            //set up different variables from the array
            //update the returned_info div with the new data
          })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Upload your file here:
  <input type="file" id="uploadfile">
  <button onclick="sendfile()">Submit!</button>
</form>

<div id="returned_info">
  
</div>
```

Is the above code correct, or is there anything I can improve?

How would I properly receive the request in the python server, so it can convert that CSV file to an array, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173892/convert-from-csv-to-array-in-python)? After the server is done getting data and making calculations from this original array, how can I have it send another array back to the HTML page to be used by jQuery callback (See code)?

I am using [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-post-method) reference.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information on what kind of framework you are using for your python backend? For example, Django, Flask, etc. Also, could you provide th HTML for sending the file as well as the relevant backend code?

Comment: `POST` can send more data. For rest you have to learn JavaScript or use `jQuery.post()`. For server AJAX requests is like normal request so there is no difference - only it doesn't have to send full HTML but only part of HTML or JSON data and then JavaScript in browser has to get it and replace part of HTML.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I added my js and html code. I will be using flask, is this a good way to get started: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data? Thank you!

Comment: first you should check [file upload](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) and build it without JavaScript and later add JavaScript. BTW: and you need `name=` in `<input>` to access it in `Flask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you don't use jQuery and build it only with pure JavaScript.

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` only to make it simpler for tests - you can put all in one file and run it.

Url `/` display form with JavaScrip which use `XHR/AJAX` to send file to `/upload` and get result

Url `/upload` gets file from form and generate HTML with result which sends back to browser.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, render_template_string
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '.'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="my_file" />
    <input type="submit" id="my_button" value="Send" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
var my_form = document.getElementById("my_form");
var my_file = document.getElementById("my_file");
var my_button = document.getElementById("my_button");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

my_button.onclick = function(event){

    var formData = new FormData(my_form);
    formData.append('my_file', my_file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Add any event handlers here...
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        // HTTP status message
        //console.log(xhr.status);
        // request.response will hold the response from the server
        //console.log(xhr.response);
        result.innerHTML = xhr.response;
    });

    xhr.send(formData);

    event.preventDefault(); 
};
</script>

</body>

</html>''')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():

    #if request.method == 'POST': # no need if `methods=['POST']` 
    #if request.is_xhr():  # `is_xhr()` doesn't exist any more

    # get file     
    #print(request.files)
    temp_file = request.files.get('my_file')  #  `<input ... name="my_file">`
    print(temp_file.filename)

    # save it in 
    save_name = secure_filename(temp_file.filename)
    full_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], save_name)
    temp_file.save(full_path)

    #data = pd.read_csv(full_path)
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Text': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
        'Number': [123, 456, 789],
    })
    print(data)

    # convert dataFrame to HTML 
    table = data.to_html() 
    #table = data.to_html(classes="my_table", header=True) 

    # send generated HTML
    return table

    # or

    # send template with embed HTML. It  needs `|safe` to display HTML correctly
    #return render_template_string('''DataFrame:</br>{{ table|safe }}</br>''', table=table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** version with `jQuery` needs only changes in `<script>` in `HTML`.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="my_file" name="my_file" />
    <input type="submit" id="my_button" value="Send" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
//$("#my_form").submit(function(event){     
// or
$("#my_button").click(function(event){     
    $.post({
        url: '/upload',
        data: new FormData($("#my_form")[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, // Using FormData, no need to process data.
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("An error occurred, the files couldn't be sent!");
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});    

// warning: when I was using `alert(event)` or `alert($("#my_form")[0])` to see values in Firefox then code doesn't work
</script>

</body>

</html>''')
```

**BTW:** in Firefox JavaScript code didn't work when I try to use `alert(event)` or 
`alert($("#my_form")[0])`

Comment: Thank you! I can see how this one-file setup is useful for testing. If I ever wanted to keep the HTML file separate, would that work too, if it is in the same directory?

Comment: if you what to keep HTML in separated files then you have to put them in subfolder `templates` because it is Flask's default folder for templates. And you use only filename without folder name `templates` - `return render_template('index.html')` or if you have `templates/other/index.html` then `render_template('other/index.html')`

Comment: I have tried this and it works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you for the guidance!